# Move iTunes media files to a different location

Tags: itunes, music

I'm organising my iTunes media in two folder myself `/Volumes/Data/Music` and `/Volumes/Data/OtherMusic`. My 2nd hard-drive port (yes, the port, not the HDD itself) died so I copied all music to `Volumes/System/Users/Me/Music/Music` and `Volumes/System/Users/Me/Music/OtherMusic`

How do I change all tracks in the library to be connected to the new location **WITHOUT**

- consolidating all files
- loosing playlists
- changing the folder structure

if I have to tinker with bash and RegEx that is fine too.

Comment: Have you tried in the iTunes Preferences > Advanced and then change the iTunes Media folder location with the one you have copied.

Comment: There's a long [& ultimately unsatisfying] method here - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230207/how-to-share-an-itunes-library-between-mac-windows/230208#230208 It used to work better before iTunes 12.3 :/ It doesn't answer your question directly, but gives a working method for manual data management.

Comment: @Tetsujin This is really unsatisfying so I'm better off giving in and let iTunes manage the music itself?

Comment: 'Better off'... in terms of convenience I'd say yes. iTunes is really meant to be a 'set & forget' experience. Trying to keep a track of its foibles manually is not the most fun you can have on a rainy afternoon. Having said that, I still, to this day, have a Win PC using the same 'repository' as my Mac & I still periodically go through all that to keep it in approximate sync.

Comment: btw, your 'difficulty' is really only that you are trying to maintain two library folders in one library. If you merge [or possibly even just consolidate] them, iTunes can then take over with no issues

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Install iTunes

Step 2: Move any new content

Step 3: Copy the iTunes backup from your old computer

Step 4 (optional): Add back new content