# How do I change the location of the Music folder on macOS?

Tags: macos, itunes

How can I change the location of the Music folder from `/Users/Me/Music` to an external drive, so that iTunes saves its stuff there?

This is so that I can access the XML file that you can create from iTunes for Windows programs to use. And yes, I know that the file paths are not the same, but it will still be helpful.

Comment: Key issue here is that the Music folder can't be easily moved any more. So you might geht better answers if you are more specific about the real-world problem you want to solve with moving the folder. You mention macOS paths but also Windows, so what exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: I'm trying to have a shareable iTunes XML file for Windows, that will (sorta) work from both sides

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230207/how-to-share-an-itunes-library-between-mac-windows/ for why this will probably not work

Comment: That's fine, I get that, but is it actually impossible to move the Music folder? Or at least have macOS sync the XML file over to an exFAT partition>

Comment: You can set up a cron/launchd job to copy the file every minute or so.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the folder iTunes uses directly in iTunes -> Preferences:

[image]

Comment: I know about that, I'm talking about the library files(the .itl files). That's why I want to change the Music folder's location altogether

Comment: @PiAhoy Can you please edit your question to be more specific about what you want to accomplish?

Comment: Done. I just want to move the location of the Music folder to a different partition.