# Convert .musiclibrary to .itl? (Migrating music library from Catalina to Windows 10)

Tags: itunes, windows, music, migration

I recently had to make the switch to my Windows 10 machine and need a way to transfer my music library from my Mac to PC. Shift-click iTunes in Windows to choose a new library file doesn't work with .musiclibrary files, it only accepts .itl.

Reimporting every single song into the Windows iTunes is my last resort since my library is large and that would take a while. Any alternatives?

Thank you.

Comment: iTunes Library paths are absolute, so that won't work even if it would import it. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230207/how-to-share-an-itunes-library-between-mac-windows for how it used to work… but I'm not sure you can do that any more since the .itl became the 'master' rather than the .xml

Comment: My iTunes library is on an external drive so it should remain as the same path if I just plug the drive into my PC and none of the directory names change...?

Comment: Mac Path: /Volumes/Drive Name/iTunes stuff/ Windows path: D:\\iTunes stuff\ *Ne'er the twain shall meet.*

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I'm really hoping to not add my music files manually, but it looks like that's the only option. When I eventually revert back to Mac (holding out for the new ARM ones), will I run into the same file path issue with taking my Windows .itl file and using it on the Mac to initialize/setup the Music app?

Comment: Yes, you'll hit the same issue. That answer of mine hasn't been checked since the last edit in 2017, so I really don't know if there's a good replacement method any more. I no longer have any Windows machines to check on. I'd at least give the 'post 12.3' method a try, see if it does still work. Even though the answer is for a remote location, it ought to work for a local one [if it still works at all].

Comment: & I've just realised .musiclibrary  is the new Catalina format, about which I unfortunately know absolutely nothing, as none of the Macs here can run it.